# Erro de consulta no SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou tentando fazer um consulta no banco para liberação de acesso. Quando faço a seguinte consulta:

```
<?php

   if(isset($_POST['Login'])){
      $user = $_POST['user'];
      $password = $_POST['pass'];
      $sql = MySql::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tb_admin.usuarios` WHERE user = ? AND pass = ?");
      $sql->execute(array($user,$password));
      if($sql->rowCount() == 1){
          $_SESSION['login'] = true;
          header('Location: '.PATH);
      }else{
          echo '<script> alert("Nome de Usuário ou senha incorreto!"); </script>';
      }
  }

?>
```

O navegador me apresenta o seguinte erro:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'pass' in 'where clause

Como posso resolver?

Comment: o erro diz que não existe a coluna `pass` na tabela `usuarios` que tá no banco `tb_admin`

Comment: Muito Obrigado mesmo, resolveu aqui